# Is a possible to check number of rows affected by update query in oracle without executing the query

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to check number of rows affected by update query in oracle without executing the query for production environment, is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could run `EXPLAIN` on your update query.  The output from that would include things like row counts at each step of the query pipeline.  In addition, `EXPLAIN` would be making its estimates using table *statistics*, rather than hitting the actual production table.

Comment: EXPLAIN keyword doesn't work for me, i am getting ORA-06550

Comment: @dev123 Use: `EXPLAIN PLAN FOR UPDATE yourTable ...`

Answer (score 2):

Instead of an `UPDATE` use a `SELECT` statement with the same `WHERE` filters and use `COUNT(*)` to get the number of rows; you will get an exact count of the rows without updating them.

You could also use the table statistics, but if your statistics are stale then the estimate given may not accurately reflect the actual number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

You could refer the `v$sql`  table to view the query history or as one of the above answers as `Explain`.

Also, You could create a one time manual trigger and set it to on a update of a table to get in action on Update

```
        Eg. Create Trigger tname 
               After Update
               on
               Table for each row

               ..... SELECT count(:new.id)...etc
```

Comment: And how does 'get sql history' return a count of rows that would be affected by an UN-exectured update?   And how does an AFTER UPDATE trigger return a count of rows that would be affected by an UN-exectured update?